# datetime-local time format does not conform to the required format

Tags: html, django, postgresql, datetime

I hope this question is not a duplicate - I was at least not able to fix the issue by looking at other similar Q&As.

I'm making a web application using Django 2.2, Postgresql 9.5 and Django template language with bootstrap for front end.

In settings.py I have the following time settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

In some of my forms I have datetime-local fields:

```
date = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(
        attrs={
            'type':'datetime-local',
            'class':'form-control',
        }
    ))
```

In my Django template I render the date field as shown below:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="id_date" class="form-control" value="{{ basic_form.date.value|date:"c"}}">
```

I'm getting the following error when loading a page with date field having a date value retrieved from database. And I'm not able to display the date in the form date field:

> The specified value "2020-10-28T09:28:00+00:00" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

I have also tried to 'render' the date field in the template directly from the form variable received by views.py:

```
{{ basic_form.date }}
```

...and then I get a same warning, however the date value does not contain the T 'separator':

> The specified value "2020-10-28 09:28:00+00:00" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

Not sure how to interpret this warning message as to me it seems like the date is on the correct format.

On the server side I get a Runtime warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Recipe.date received a naive datetime (2020-10-28 09:28:00) while time zone support is active.

Does anyone know how to get the date displayed in the date field and the date value further utilized in the application by javascript? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping off the `tzinfo` is not the right way to make a naive datetime. It works when your current time zone is `UTC`, as it seems to be now, but will break otherwise.    Instead use Django's [`make_naive()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_naive), which will correctly convert the time into the local time zone first.

```
date = make_naive(date)
```

Alternatively, just leave it as an aware datetime (Django's template engine will convert it to the local time automatically) and just [specify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) the right string format explicitly (something like `value|date(Y-m-d H:i:s)`).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Using make_naive() from django.utils.timezone works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the timezone info (+00:00) added at the end of datetime.datetime object. In views.py when processing the data from database query I added this line:

```
date = date.replace(tzinfo=None)
```